# Network authentication through software

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, virtualization

I am working as a consultant at a (client) company for a longer period of time. This client is deploying network authentication through a software tool shortly.

Although I understand their reasons for doing this, I don't want to install this piece of software on my primary PC for obvious privacy reasons. I was thinking of installing it on a virtual machine, and then use this virtual machine as a gateway/vpn/router to the customer network.
I have tried to bring this up with the customer, but they are playing the "security is important so we dont care about your objections"-card.

I am comfortable in networking concepts, but I am not sure how to set this up from a virtualisation point of view. 
So far I figured out that I could allow the VM to use the physical (ethernet cable) interface, and I am thinking of setting up a host-only interface to the VM as a way of transporting traffic. 
However I am not sure how to configure my native OS (Windows 10).

Will this be a proper solution?

I could use VMware workstation or Virtualbox as a hypervisor. Resources (RAM/HDD) won't be a problem.

Comment: Just configure the VM so it has access to the network you are connected to with an IP address in the same range with DHCP or a static assignment, and then from that VM host, connect to the VPN, or the company network, etc. and install the software that authenticates or whatever. It should work just fine.